# How to merge images?

Tags: c++, image, merge

I want to merge two different images. 
Is there some library to do it ?

(.net platform or in unmanaged code (C++))

Comment: In which language on which platform?

Comment: ITYM "merge". To be able to answer your question you should specify what platform you're on and what you mean by "merge" - an example image would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AlphaBlend function see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/alphablend.aspx) and [here](http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Codes/GDI-AlphaBlend-Bitmap-Alpha-vc-example.htm)